# Count unique values in a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array `${sorted[@]}`. How can I count the frequency of occurrence of the elements of the array.

e.g:

**Array values:**

```
bob
jane
bob
peter
```

**Results:**

```
bob 2
jane 1
peter 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The command

```
(IFS=$'\n'; sort <<< "${array[*]}") | uniq -c
```

#### Explanation

- Counting occurrences of unique lines is done with the idiom `sort file | uniq -c`.
- Instead of using a file, we can also feed strings from the command line to `sort` using the *here string* operator `<<<`.
- Lastly, we have to convert the array entries to lines inside a single string. With `${array[*]}` the array is expanded to one single string where the array elements are separated by `$IFS`.
- With `IFS=$'\n'` we set the `$IFS` variable to the newline character for this command exclusively. The `$'...'` is called *ANSI-C Quoting* and allows us to express the newline character as `\n`.
- The subshell `(...)` is there to keep the change of `$IFS` local. After the command `$IFS` will have the same value as before.

#### Example

```
array=(fire air fire earth water air air)
(IFS=$'\n'; sort <<< "${array[*]}") | uniq -c
```

prints

```
      3 air
      1 earth
      2 fire
      1 water
```

Comment: @user9487425 The old answer worked on bash 3.2 but not on bash 4.3 (wouldn't have expected that). I updated the answer to work on both versions.